# Suppress banner for `ssh` or `scp`

Tags: ssh

Is there a way to suppress the banner output that's sent from `sshd` using the `Banner` option when using ssh clients like `ssh` or `scp`?

I've looked at the options and config file, but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Set `Banner` to `none` in `sshd_config`?

Comment: @SatoKatsura: I can't control the sshd_config as I'm not root on that box, unfortunately...

Comment: see also https://serverfault.com/a/737622/482932

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the `-q` (quiet) option to ssh and scp, to suppress the `/etc/motd` (and related) messages.

While `Banner` might seem to be related, it is not.  Refer to [`sshd_config`](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) manual:

> The contents of the specified file are sent to the remote user before authentication is allowed. If the argument is none then no banner is displayed. **By default, no banner is displayed**.

You could use `PrintMotd` (in [`sshd_config`](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config)):

> **`PrintMotd`**
>       Specifies whether [sshd(8)](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8) should print `/etc/motd` when a user logs in interactively. (On some systems it is also printed by the shell, `/etc/profile`, or equivalent.) The default is yes.

but in scripting, I simply use the `-q` option (requiring less configuration of the server).

Comment: Thanks, `-q` also works to supress the Banner.

Comment: "-q" on Solaris 5.10 did not suppress the banner, only the file transfer status.

Comment: works for ssh, Thanks. I also try via gitbash did scp to Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus) "-q" suppress banner and file transfer status. Would be great if the file transfer status is kept. :/

Comment: Unfortunately, `-q` suppresses **everything**.  Too bad there's only a "suppress banner".