# After SSH login linux output a kernel version

Tags: linux, ssh, banner

I can't hide or delete the banner when I'm logging in via ssh. This is my example: "Linux aedd7472f871 6.1.0-kali5-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.12-1kali2 (2023-02-23) x86_64"

[image]

How do I delete this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Add the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Banner /etc/banner
```

or

```
Banner /folder/mybannerfile
```

Write the message you want in the file and restart `sshd`

[**Option 2:**](https://askubuntu.com/a/32802/158442)

> It seems it is possible to disable this message on a user basis by
> creating an empty file in a user's `$HOME` directory
> (`/home/username/`) called `.hushlogin`
>
> ```
> touch ~/.hushlogin
> ```

[**Option 3:**](https://askubuntu.com/a/408873/158442)

> In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` make sure there is a line:
>
> ```
> PrintMotd no
> ```

[**Option 4:**](https://askubuntu.com/a/682881/158442)

> `.hushlogin` didn't do the trick for me, but setting Banner to
> `/dev/null` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` :
>
> ```
> Banner /dev/null
> ```

Sources:

- [Suppress banner for `ssh` or `scp`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320039/suppress-banner-for-ssh-or-scp)
- [How can I disable/modify the SSH login banner for a given user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32800/how-can-i-disable-modify-the-ssh-login-banner-for-a-given-user)
- [Disable SSH MOTD/Banner for a specific user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474752/disable-ssh-motd-banner-for-a-specific-user)